# CAPL writing to Text file

Tags: capl, canoe

I am pretty new to the CAPL language. Hence, I am having problems with writing data to .txt file. This is the code I wrote:

```
    includes
{

}

variables
{
  message Generate_Num Gen;
  message Logger Logs;
  msTimer tim_100ms;
  msTimer tim_500ms;
  int time_over; // 500 ms flag.
  dword handle=0;
  float val=0;
  long index=0;
  int val_arr[512];
}

on start 
{
  time_over=0; 
  setWritePath("C:\\Users\\Türker\\Desktop\\soft_pro");
  handle= openFileWrite("Log.txt",1);
  Gen.Num_Data=1;
}

on envVar Logger_Sw
{   

    if(@this)
    {
      setTimer(tim_500ms,500);
      setTimer(tim_100ms,100);
    }
    else
    {
      cancelTimer(tim_500ms);
      cancelTimer(tim_100ms);
    }

}

on envVar Save_txt
{   
  if(@Save_txt==1)
    {
      int i;
      float val_n;
      for(i=0;i<elcount(val_arr);i++)
      {
        val_n=val_arr[i];
        writeProfileFloat("1","1",val_n,"Log.txt");
      }
    } 
}

on timer tim_100ms
{
  output(Gen);
  Gen.Num_Data++; 
  setTimer(tim_100ms,100);
}

on message Generate_Num
{
  if(time_over==1)
  {
   val=this.Num_Data;
   val_arr[index]=val; 
   Logs.Logged_Val=val;
   output(Logs);
   index++; 
   time_over=0;
  }

}

on timer tim_500ms
{
  time_over=1;
  setTimer(tim_500ms,500);
}
```

I store the sampled data in "val_arr" array. I want this to be written in a text file. However, it always overwrites the written data. The "Save_txt" environmental variable does the writing job.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple example of writing the value of variable as it is incremented.

```
variables 
{
  dword logFile;        // logfile handle
  int i;                
  char results[1024];   // store our formatted string
}

on start 
{
  setFilePath("C:\\Demo\\Results", 2);       // 2 = read & write
  logFile = openFileWrite("Results.txt", 2); // 2 = append file

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) 
  {
    snprintf(results, 1024, "The value of 'i' is %d\n", i);
    filePutString(results, 1024, logFile);       
  }
  fileClose(logFile);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Open your file in a different access mode.

```
OpenFileWrite ("Log.txt",2);
```

If mode=0 writing can be executed in ASCII mode; 
if mode=1 writing can be executed in binary mode. An already existing file will be overwritten.
mode=2 to append data at the end of the file use for ASCII mode.
mode=3 to append data at the end of the file for binary mode.