# Is it possible to write the code that will send an email if VECTOR Canoe stopped the measurement?

Tags: capl, canoe

Because of my test environment, VECTOR Canoe occasionally stops the measurement by itself. So I have an idea to send an email every time that the measurement stopped.

Thank you for all of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not be CAPL, but you could use CAPL to write a file with the error and a timestamp, and then have a python script running on background which simply reads the content of the file and sends it by email.

You have to write to the file in the handler `on stopMeasurament{<your code> }`.

[Here it is how to write a file in CAPL (StackOverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116595/capl-writing-to-text-file)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have implemented this to our test environment and it is working fine! Thank you so much :D